# Adding hyperlinks to names with vba

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

My VBA skills are nonexistent, and I have not been able to find any threads that fit my situation, hence this thread.

I have a column in an Excel sheet containing names (column B) and I'm trying to hyperlink the cells in B to web pages. There's one specific web page for each row.

It'd be easy to just use the HYPERLINK function if I have a column with all of the corresponding URLS but the problem is that the final version of the spreadsheet will not have a column with URLs.

What the final version will include:
(column B) names hyperlinked to specific web pages, and 
(column A) IDs that includes a unique part of the URL plus the name from B

The URLs are all identical except for the number at the end.
The part that doesn't change is:

```
http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=CFPB-2011-0008
```

and there's a four-digit number at the end for each URL.

The bit starting with "CFPB" and ending with the four-digit number is the part that's going to be included in column A.

So my plan is to write a VBA program that adds hyperlinks to B using URLs constructed from

```
http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=
```

and the front part of the corresponding cells in A (e.g. CFPB-2011-0008-0002). I'm thinking of using the LEFT function to get this second part of the URL from A (e.g. LEFT(A1,19)).

Sorry if the explanation is not clear... Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Will not work. Because of the `#` within the URL. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202261

Comment: @AxelRichter - Worked fine for URLs (at least when I tried it in Excel 2010).  The only weird thing was that the tooltip replaced the # with a hyphen, but it still loaded the correct page when clicked. The KB linked only refers to using a `#` in filenames.

Comment: @Comintern. Your answer works not with Excel 2007. The hyperlink calls `http://www.regulations.gov/%20-%20!documentDetail;D=CFPB-2011-0008` which fails.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Interesting.  I wonder if they fixed that in Excel 2010.

Comment: @Comintern: Seems to be a problem of combination Excel 2007 and IE 11 as default browser. With Chrome as default browser, it works.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Weird.  I'd initially tried it with Firefox as my default browser, but it also worked with a combo of Excel 2010 and IE11.

Comment: @Comintern: *lol* funny Microsoft ;-). Now, after changing the default browser to Chrome and back to IE, it works for me with IE as new setted default browser also. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070176/hyperlink-changes-from-to-20-20-when-clicked-in-excel answer from Daniel and comment from twip.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question correctly, you can do this with a simple worksheet function.  Just concatenate the URL together:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=",LEFT(A1,14)))
```

One VBA solution to just add URLs to the existing document names would be something like:

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

    Dim url As String

    Dim current As Range
    For Each current In Selection.Cells
        url = "http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=" & _
              Left$(current.Value, 14)
        current.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add current, url
    Next current

End Sub
```

Select the cells you want to add hyperlinks to and run the macro.

Comment: I ran this just now and it works perfectly except that it looks like the url that shows up ends with the first 14 characters of the name in column A instead of the the ID in column B. I would like to hyperlink the names while referencing the IDs. Supposing the column with IDs is to the left of the column with names, is there a way to replace current.Value in the Left function with something that means "the cell to the left of the active cell"? Thank you very much.

Comment: @hwin - you can replace `current.Value` with `current.Offset(0, -1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

I put a script together the other day to do something similar, you'll want to put it into a loop or something to go through your list in the spreadsheet. I use iCurrentRow and iCurrentCol to navigate round my sheet.

Use the functions you suggested to build the hyperlink string in the cell you want it in i.e. the cells in Column B, and then set the strString to this value. I've added strString in just now (has not been tested), so if it doesn't work then you may need to encompass it inside CStr().

It should give you something to work from anyway.

```
' Set the string to the hyperlink address    
strString = Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol).value
' Check if the cell already has a hyperlink
If Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    'If it does then check if it is the same as in the cell
     If strString  <> CStr(Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol).Hyperlinks(1).Address) Then
         'Check if there is no new hyperlink
          If strString = "" Then
              Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol).Hyperlinks.Delete
          Else
              ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol), _
                  Address:=strString
          End If
      End If
Else
    'If there isn't an existing hyperlink then add it
     If strString <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(iCurrentRow, iCurrentCol), _
             Address:=strString 
     End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim rng As Range, rr As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each rr In rng
        If rr.Value <> "" Then
            Set r = rr
            Call hyper_maker(r)
        End If
    Next rr
End Sub

Sub hyper_maker(r As Range)
    If r.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        r.Hyperlinks.Delete
    End If
    txt = r.Value
    s = "http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=" & txt
    r.Value = s
    r.Select
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    DoEvents
    r.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = txt
End Sub
```